# Subset Sum with two sets and target

Tags: python, algorithm, subset, mathematical-optimization, subset-sum

i am a bit puzzled here on solving this computation . I managed to create a subset sum program using python . Here is the code :

```
def subsetsum(array,num):

    if num == 0 or num < 1:
        return None
    elif len(array) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        if array[0] == num:
            return [array[0]]
        else:
            with_v = subsetsum(array[1:],(num - array[0])) 
            if with_v:
                return [array[0]] + with_v
            else:
                return subsetsum(array[1:],num)
```

My question is , what if i have two sets of array namely array1=[4,5,1,7,2,1] and array2=[7,1,4,6,3,2] in which the target is 18 in a way array 1 should have a target of 8 and array 2 a target of 10 .

Also what if i have arrays that has bigger margin of error . how would i reduce it ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Following your example, `arr1=[4,5,1,7,2,1]`, `arr2=[7,1,4,6,3,2]` and `target=18`, you can use a set to save the difference between each element in `arr1` and the target, next iterate `arr2` and check if the element is in the set, if that's the case then you have found one number in `arr1` and one number in `arr2` that summed are equal to the target.

```
def getSubsetSum(arr1, arr2, target):
    diffs = set()
    for a in arr1:
        diffs.add(target - a)
    for b in arr2:
        if b in diffs:
            return (target -b, b)
    return None
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , let me test it , if it works will tick it . Thanks again .